# Recognize when ssh session closed

Tags: command-line, ssh, gnome-terminal

I was trying to change my terminal profile when connecting with ssh to a remote computer. This works well with a certain number of local profiles and `xdotool key Alt+t p Down Return`.

Now the question is how to recognize if a ssh session is closed in the terminal. Like when you press C-d it shows logout and connection closed. But is there a way to see if I'm back in my old session. Like is there some file reloaded when closing the ssh session? As much as I know is .bashrc not again executed, but maybe anything else.

```
user@remote-pc:~$ logout
Connection to remote-pc closed.
DO_SOMETHING_HERE
user@local-pc:~$
```

Since the profile has to be changed on the local machine is it necessary to run the command locally. So it can't be run with .bash_logout since this will be run on the remote machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with a function around the normal ssh. now changes the color depending on the server and changes it back when returning to the local host.

```
alias blue='xdotool key --delay 50 Alt+t p Return'
alias dark='xdotool key --delay 50 Alt+t p Down Return'
alias green='xdotool key --delay 50 Alt+t p Down Down Return'
alias red='xdotool key --delay 50 Alt+t p Down Down Down Return'


cssh(){
  if [[ $1 == *"remote1"* ]]
  then
    green
  elif [[ $1 == *"remote2"* ]]
  then
    red
  else
    blue
  fi
  ssh $@
  sleep 0.5
  dark
}
```